# Copying files from command line to clipboard

Tags: command-line, x11, clipboard

In a GUI file manager it is possible to select a few files, press Ctrl-C (which supposedly copies come info about the files to clipboard), then navigate to another folder and press Ctrl-V, which will then copy the files into that directory.

As an experiment, after copying files in the file manager, it is possible to switch to a text editor - pressing Ctrl-V there pastes a list of absolute filenames. The reverse process (copying a list of files from a text editor and pasting them to a file manager) does not work, which is supposedly due to different [target atoms](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.6.2)

The goal of the exercise is to be able to copy some files from command line, for example

```
find ${PWD} -name "*.txt" | xclip <magic parameters>
```

then switch to a file manager and copy them all to a directory using File->Paste.

So, the question is: What parameters of `xclip` (or other program) do I need to specify so file manager recognizes the selection as a list of files and enables its Paste menu item?

Alternatively, is there a low-level tool which would allow to inspect the contents of X selection and see what data it currently contains?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, basically, you'd need to offer the CLIPBOARD selection either as

- `text/uri-list` with the content being

  ```
  /path/to/file1
  /path/to/file2
  ```
- `application/x-kde-cutselection` or `x-special/gnome-copied-files` with content `copy\nfile://$path1\nfile://$path2\0` or `cut\nfile://$path1\nfile://$path2...\0`

With `xclip` you can achieve this with something like

```
find "$PWD" -name "*.pdf"| xclip -i -selection clipboard -t text/uri-list
```

I've also found this [loliclip](https://github.com/Cloudef/PKGBUILDS/tree/master/loliclip) command that looked promising, but though I could retrieve the values, I wasn't able to store them and have them retrieved from `loliclip` by `pcmanfm` successfully.

You also should be able to implement it in a few lines of `perl-tk`.

Comment: Ok, after some tinkering the `text/uri-list` variant worked for me - I'm able to copy stuff from command line and paste files into Dolphin file manager. It doesn't even require `file://` prefixes, which make the command to work fine with `find`. I've edited your question to add the command which works for me in KDE - can anybody test it in Gnome or elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It looks like the `file://` is not necessary with `pcmanfm` either (though pcmanfm does include it itself). I suppose some special characters (at the very least LF) should be URI-encoded though.

Comment: Yes. I can confirm you need to use `file:///new%0Aline` for files that contain a newline characters, though any other character (including non-ASCII in any encoding) seems to be fine (with pcmanfm at least)

Comment: Dolphin now seems to require the `file://` scheme prefix

Answer (score 2):

Based on these answers I wrote a `filetoclip` Python script, which copies to the clipboard the files specified on the command line.

Essentially, all that's needed is to absolutize them and percent-encode "strange" characters before copying to the clipboard. The actual clipboard operation is delegated to `xclip`, as working with clipboard straight from Python is more painful than expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os.path
import sys
from urllib.parse import quote
from subprocess import run
out = [os.fsencode('file://' + quote(os.path.abspath(x))) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
run(['xclip', '-i', '-selection', 'clipboard', '-t', 'text/uri-list'],
    input=b'\n'.join(out), check=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just make `find` do it for you?

```
find ${PWD} -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} /full/path \; && gnome-open /full/path &
```

EDIT: from what I understand from `man xclip`: it handles text only, not files or directories.

Comment: Mostly because it's an experiment, although I think the "copy files to clipboard now, decide where you want to paste them later" would be a useful way to do things.